# MariaDB group by is slow

Tags: group-by, mariadb, query-optimization

I have a scenario whereby I am trying to fetch a user's most recent messages from over 2 million rows and group them by their parent (or thread) id. However, this grouping is causing the query time to be around 1s, about 1000 times slower than without the group by.

Here is the table

```
CREATE TABLE `msg` (
`msg_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`msg_to` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`msg_from` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`msg` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
`parent` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`msg_id`),
 KEY `msg_toIX` (`msg_to`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `msg_fromIX` (`msg_from`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `parentIX` (`parent`) USING BTREE ) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Here is my query

```
SELECT a.msg_id, a.msg_from, a.msg FROM msg a 
JOIN(SELECT MAX(msg_id) maxid FROM msg WHERE msg_to = 23 GROUP BY parent ORDER BY msg_id DESC LIMIT 10) b
ON a.msg_id IN (b.maxid)
ORDER BY a.msg_id DESC LIMIT 10
```

Explained
[image]

Is this as good as it gets or should I be getting better performance seeing as I can extract 10 thousand rows in 0.001 with a condition and without the group by clause? Am I going about this the wrong way?

Thanks for your continued guidance and support

**UPDATE**
Thanks everyone who contributed. O.Jones hit the nail on the head down below. Compound Index was the missing link

Comment: I'm surprised that `a.msg_id IN b.maxid` works at all. `b.maxid` is not a list that something can be `IN`. That should be `=` instead of `IN`.

Comment: When I try it I get a syntax error.

Comment: Yes I forgot to add parentheses around b.maxid but just edited them in. But either = or IN ( ) does not seem to alter the outcome

Comment: What do you *think* the ORDER BY in the subquery achieves? And what version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: There's no difference between `IN (onevalue)` and `= onevalue`. Only use `IN` when you have multiple items. But I expect the parser to treat them equivalently.

Comment: @MatBailie Since the problem is performance, a minimal example won't demonstrate it. You need millions of rows.

Comment: @barmar unless the ***logic*** can be rewritten, such as to avoid the self join.

Comment: @MatBailie Even so, you won't be able to tell if it solved the performance problem. The best you can do is verify that it returns the same results.

Comment: Have you tried using a window function instead of join? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql?rq=1 for examples.

Comment: @barmar Without a sufficently precise description of the intended behaviour, it's not possible to determine is a self join is even necessary. If the OP desires alternative formulations, which may be substantially cheaper to execute, an mre is very warranted.

Comment: @MatBailie Give me a break. This is the same "max row in each group" question that comes up a dozen times a day. Except that this one is about performance, not the basic query structure.

Comment: @MatBailie I am using mysql version 10.4.11. Not sure what I expected out of the order by in the subquery, seemed pretty sweet at the time

Comment: That's not a MySQL version number, it's a MariaDB version. Although I don't think there's much difference for the purposes of this question.

Comment: I edited the title and tags to make it more clear it's a question about MariaDB, not MySQL. Sometimes the answer is the same for both, but we should all get into the habit of thinking of MySQL and MariaDB as two different products. They are becoming more incompatible over time, and an answer for one is not necessarily applicable to the other.

Comment: @BillKarwin I will take your word for it seeing as I could not even ascertain my version correctly!

Comment: @MatBailie Turns out the ORDER BY in the sub query is required. Without it the results are not what they should be. It is actually the ORDER BY and LIMIT in the outer query which are redundant

Comment: @midget You're ordering by an expression not in the GROUP BY or an aggregate. Do you mean `ORDER BY MAX(msg_id) DESC`? *(Also, be aware that the database is free to assign id's out of order, you should never rely on an identity for time ordering, use your timestamp for that.)*

Comment: @MatBailie Yes I did mean MAX(msg_id) DESC, but acutually it is the LIMIT in the sub query which is messing with the results. Without the LIMIT the query goes from 0.04s to 0.2s which still seems very fast for a few million records, but with limit the result omits a huge range of rows. I guess I should quit while I'm still ahead

Comment: Why would you include the limit in the question and then remove it?  Is the question not actually what you want to do?  I strongly suggest making an example with dummy data and desired results; [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: @MatBailie Not quite sure what you mean by remove it from the question. Do you mean remove it from the query? I included the limit in the query to improve the performance and then excluded it as it is messing with the results. Sorry, but I am not able to fill the tables with data at this time

Comment: Optimising for `the latest message in each of the 10 most recently active threads` is very different to optimising for `the latest message in all threads`.  Your question should cover the actual functionality you want, not some hybrid-debug version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a bit of input from everyone I will answer the question fully.

I initially included the LIMIT in the JOIN sub query as this helped to speed it up. O.Jones advice of compound index on 3 fields helped take the query time from 1s down to 0.04s but then I noticed that the results were omitting a huge range of rows. I re-included the ORDER BY in the sub query which corrected the results but took the query up to 0.2s.

Switching the order of the index from (msg_to, parent, msg_id) - as per O.Jones' answer - to (parent,msg_to,msg_id) resulted in the new index to be used in the GROUP BY, reducing scanned rows in DERIVED table from 1 million+ down to 61 and query time to 0.000s, also allowing for the omission of ORDER BY and LIMIT in sub query.

So the correct query in is

```
SELECT a.msg_id, a.msg_from, a.msg FROM msg a 
JOIN(SELECT MAX(msg_id) maxid FROM msg WHERE msg_to = 23 GROUP BY parent) b
ON a.msg_id = b.maxid
ORDER BY a.msg_id DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

With Index:

```
CREATE INDEX parent_to_id ON msg (parent, msg_to, msg_id);
```

[image: Explained]

Thanks everybody. Truth be told, it was a pretty awesome question which deserved some up votes. I'm sure someone will find it useful in the future :)

Comment: This still assumes that the max id is the newest message. That is ***not*** guaranteed. Identity columns can be allocated out of order, they should not be used for anything other than uniqueness.

Comment: That seems retarded. They should fix that

Comment: It's like that on all databases.

Answer (score 1):

Create a composite index for both `parent` and `msg_id` so that getting the maximum ID for each parent is optimized.

```
CREATE TABLE `msg` (
`msg_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`msg_to` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`msg_from` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`msg` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
`parent` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`msg_id`),
 KEY `msg_toIX` (`msg_to`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `msg_fromIX` (`msg_from`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `parentIX` (`parent`, msg_id) USING BTREE ) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. I tried this but it didn't seem to make any difference. Silly question but does retroactively altering the index have the same effect on the data as creating it from the outset?

Comment: Yes, they should be the same.

Comment: Did you try the window function solution in the linked question?

Comment: I have not yet. Looks like I may need a little time to figure that one out

Comment: I tried to get Bill's example from the link but that did not work at all. Other examples down the page took the same amount of time. Maybe that's the best that can be done

Answer (score 1):

Try this compound index. It [covers](https://planetscale.com/learn/courses/mysql-for-developers/indexes/covering-indexes), I believe, your inner query.

```
CREATE INDEX to_parent_id ON msg (msg_to, parent, msg_id);
```

The inner query should be fulfillable by a [range scan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-optimization.html) on this index.

Comment: Thank you Jonesy! That fixed it. Query time went from 0.9s to 0.04s and the new compound index was utilized. A good lesson learned on compound indices. You have yourself a blessed day. Actually make it a blessed week!

Comment: Had to de-select your answer. Correct order should be (parent, msg_to, msg_id). If you can fix it up I will re-select it. This correct order made all the difference as I realized the LIMIT clause in the sub query was making the query super fast, yet it was messing with the result and omitting many rows. Adding ORDER BY in sub query fixed it but slowed down the query. Correct order now knocked query FROM 0.2s to 0s, thereby eliminating the need for LIMIT in sub query

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `msg` (
`msg_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`msg_to` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`msg_from` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`msg` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
`parent` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`msg_id`),
 INDEX (`msg_to`, `parent`, `date`, `msg_id`) USING BTREE
)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

```
INSERT INTO
  msg (
    msg_to,
    msg_from,
    msg,
    date,
    parent
  )
VALUES
  (23, 11, 'a', '2023-01-01 10:34:56.78', 1),
  (23, 11, 'b', '2023-01-01 11:34:56.78', 2),
  (23, 11, 'c', '2023-01-01 12:34:56.78', 3),

  (23, 22, 'd', '2023-01-01 11:34:56.78', 1),
  (23, 22, 'e', '2023-01-01 12:34:56.78', 2),
  (23, 22, 'f', '2023-01-01 13:34:56.78', 3),

  (23, 23, 'g', '2023-01-01 12:34:56.78', 1),
  (23, 23, 'h', '2023-01-01 13:34:56.78', 2),
  (23, 23, 'i', '2023-01-01 14:34:56.78', 3),

  (23, 11, 'j', '2023-01-01 13:34:56.78', 1),
  (23, 11, 'k', '2023-01-01 14:34:56.78', 2),
  (23, 11, 'l', '2023-01-01 15:34:56.78', 3),

  (23, 22, 'm', '2023-01-01 14:34:56.78', 1),
  (23, 22, 'n', '2023-01-01 15:34:56.78', 2),
  (23, 22, 'o', '2023-01-01 16:34:56.78', 3)
;
```

> ```
> Records: 15  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
WITH
  sorted AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() 
      OVER (
        PARTITION BY msg_to, parent
            ORDER BY date DESC, msg_id DESC
      )
        AS thread_msg_id
  FROM
    msg
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  sorted
WHERE
      msg_to        = 23
  AND thread_msg_id = 1
ORDER BY
  date DESC, msg_id DESC
LIMIT
  2
```

| msg_id | msg_to | msg_from | msg | date | parent | thread_msg_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | 23 | 22 | o | 2023-01-01 16:34:56 | 3 | 1 |
| 14 | 23 | 22 | n | 2023-01-01 15:34:56 | 2 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LiJj75xq)

Comment: `INDEX (msg_to, date, msg_id) USING BTREE` ***may*** perform better on larger data sets if users are involved in very large numbers of threads.

Comment: I very much appreciate your work on this but unfortunately this query is taking 3.5s to run even with the index

Comment: @midget Did you try the index at the top of the answer? (In the DDL)

Comment: I did but to no avail